# Create a variable name which value is inside a string variable

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a variable in `VB.Net`, but the name of this variable is inside a string variable.  How should I do this?

It should be something like this:

`Dim varA As String = "varValue"`

`Dim ??? As String  'The name of this variable should be "varValue"`

Comment: You can not have variable names created dynamically. Can you explain bit more around what exact issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: what is the scenario which causes you to need this? A potential solution might be to use a Dictionary, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible. Perhaps, if you add some more context to what you are attempting we can suggest alternatives or even fix the problem you are encountering. But, as it is. nothing can be done.

Comment: If you just want to define an identifier for your variable at runtime, a `KeyValuePair` might work (or a `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of something, something))` .

Comment: You can write a new .vb source code file to disk and invoke the VB compiler on it!

Comment: As suggested, you should explain what you're trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to achieve it. We can then tell you the way it can be achieved. Why ever you think you need to do this, you don't.